# Remap Super_R to control (Fedora 22)

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, remapping

I have verified that keycode 134 (0x86) is my Super_R key on my keyboard. But I would like to remap this to control. However, I've tried nearly every permutation. What am I doing wrong?

```
user@localhost ~ % xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Caps_Lock (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

user@localhost ~ % xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_R"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
user@localhost ~ % xmodmap -e "add control = Super_R"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
```

Comment: I am not sure which DE you are using. If it is Gnome 3, Gnome may do it for you: image http://file.systutorials.com/file/2014-04-20-5555-gnome-3-win-to-ctrl.png from http://ask.systutorials.com/742/how-to-map-win-key-to-ctrl-on-linux